# ClickOnce does not unregister/re-register VSTO solutions when running from Windows 10

Tags: .net, vsto, clickonce

Release an HelloWorld add-in for Ms Word. Sign and publish via ClickOnce, with the installation folder being set to an online directory.

#### Routine to follow

1. Run the add-in setup.exe to install via ClickOnce.
2. **Assert** the add-in has been **registered** in `File / Options / Add-ins`. Close Word.
3. Go to the `Programs and Features` panel, and uninstall the ClickOnce application which corresponds to the Add-in.
4. Launch Word and **assert** the add-in has been **unregistered** from `File / Options / Add-ins`.
5. Run the add-in setup.exe to install via ClickOnce.
6. **Assert** the add-in has been **registered** in `File / Options / Add-ins`.
7. Select `Manage: COM Add-ins` and press [Go...]. Select the add-in and click [Remove].
8. Go to the `Programs and Features` panel, and uninstall the ClickOnce application which corresponds to the Add-in.
9. Run the add-in setup.exe to install via ClickOnce.
10. **Assert** the add-in has been **registered** in `File / Options / Add-ins`.

#### Results under Windows 7 + Office 365

The flow works and all steps are correct.

#### Results under Windows 10 + Office 365

The flow does not work.

- Step 4: Uninstalling the ClickOnce application has no effect on the add-in registration with Word.
- Step 10: Unregistering the add-in manually results in ClickOnce being unable to re-register it: it keeps telling the latest version of the Office Customization is already installed, which is not reflected in Word where no add-in appears as registered.

#### What to do?

I have raised several flags in the past but got no luck. I have now narrowed down the problem to Windows 10 and additional inconsistent behaviour from ClickOnce (step 4 not working).

Questions:

1. Are we really the only VSTO publisher to face this highly deterministic issue?
2. Should we call this a bug? Where could we flag it up?

---

This is a follow up to the following threads, where I never got an answer:

[Unable to re-register VSTO Add-in after choosing [Remove] from COM Add-ins window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098810/unable-to-re-register-vsto-add-in-after-choosing-remove-from-com-add-ins-windo/57103759#57103759)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3151614e-8921-4de0-8b4e-1be65537aa8f/unable-to-reregister-vsto-com-addin-after-choosing-remove-from-list-of-quotaddins?forum=vsto

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/976266bc-1ce4-4f1c-88d0-0e4e6fa14510/unable-to-reregister-ms-word-vsto-com-addin-when-deployed-through-clickonce?forum=vsto#976266bc-1ce4-4f1c-88d0-0e4e6fa14510

Comment: Are you deploying to a machine that you used to build it on?

Comment: Both machines have Visual Studio installed, but I used machine A to develop, build and sign the solution, whilst I use machine B to install it, from the Internet published location, just as any customer would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not directly linked with Windows 10, but the **version of Office**: Store or Desktop.

By default, when installing Office on a Windows 10 computer, it is installed from the Microsoft Store.
You can tell what version is installed by checking your application version in `File / Account`: to the right of the [About Word] button, you will find the version and build number, followed by one of these two options:

> Click-to-Run

Which means you have the d**esktop version installed**, or

> Microsoft Store

Which means you have the **store version installed**.

The store version causes many issues when it comes to the handling of registry keys, or even files.
This issue was resolved by Andrei Smolin from Add-in Express Support Service. He has been extremely useful and diligent by resolving within 24 hrs an issue we had for months. Worth mentioning we are not event (yet) a client.

See his [article](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2019/02/27/office-from-store-issues/) for additional details.

### What next?

Now the question is, how do we report this to Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed 'uninstall' registry key in users' profiles with VSTO apps installed - the 'UninstallString' is missing double-quotes around the VSTO manager, which has spaces within it, eg:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe /uninstall "<path-to-vsto-manifest"

... should this be:

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /uninstall "<path-to-vsto-manifest"

I don't author these, I just look after computers that have them installed. I suspect that visual studio generates these strings.

And we get errors when I support users uninstalling them from installed applications list.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue may be caused if you have built the add-in in debug on your machine and it is also installed from the deploy location.**

1. Open the “COM Add-ins” form by either

   - Go to the Developer ribbon and click on the “COM Add-ins” button
   - Go to the "File" ribbon and click on the "Options" button. Then under “Add-Ins” select “COM Add-ins” and click “Go…”
2. Select the Add-in name and click the button “Remove”
3. Then you’ll need to uninstall the Add-in from "Programs and Features"

Also, you could try

1. Type `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` in the command window and run it

Comment: Thanks Aduguid, your steps 2 and 3 correspond to my steps 7 and 8.
`rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` did not fix the problem either.

Comment: `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` does not raise any error

Comment: Sorry, I meant when you install the VSTO click-once add-in.

Comment: No error message, both Win7 and Win10 flows show the same windows/forms, except under Win10 where step 5 behaves as if step 3 had not been done (that is, ClickOnce says in a green light message that the last version of the customization is already installed). Same with step 9 which behaves as if step 7 had not been done.

Comment: Thanks for the research

Comment: No worries, here are my [Excel VSTO projects](https://github.com/Excel-projects) in GitHub

Comment: Interesting. May I ask what soft you use for recording your GIFs?